# When using subprocess.run() to launch a process on remote server with ssh, subprocess.run() doesn't wait for the process to finish

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I need to run a command from my python script on a remote server. This command translates a file `input_file` (it can take several minutes), and writes a new file with the translation `translated_file`. Next, I need to copy the translation file to the folder `translations`. However, `subprocess.run()` doesn't wait for the command to finish, and when it tries to copy, there's an error because the file doesn't exist yet.

This is the script:

```
subprocess.run(["ssh", "remote-server", "-f", "python", "-m", "sockeye.translate", "--models", "translation-model", "--input", "input_file", "--output", "translated_file"])

subprocess.run(["ssh", "remote-server", "-f", "cp", "translated_file", "translations"])
```

I think this is related to `ssh` because when I try to do the same thing on the remote server directly, `subprocess.run()` waits for the translation to finish. On the remote server I used the same command, I just removed the `ssh` remote-server , like this :

```
subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "sockeye.translate", "--models", "translaiton-model", "--input", "input_file", "--output", "translated_file"])

subprocess.run(["cp", "translated_file", "translations"])
```

How can I make `subprocess.run()` wait? Or is there a better way of running a command on remote?

Answer (score 0):

You're running `ssh` with the `-f` option. Try removing the `-f` option. That option causes `ssh` to begin running in the background after authentication. You don't want that because you want to wait for each `ssh` invocation to finish.

See the description of the option [here](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#f):

> **-f**
> **Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.** This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the background. This implies -n. The recommended way to start X11 programs at a remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.